# Volley is showing timeout error if I am using mobile data

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I tried many wifi and mobile data but it's issue just on my mobile. Whenever i try to send a volley request  get a timeout error. I don't know why just my device is causing this issue. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's related to different speed in wifi and mobile data network. you can use a large timeout value, try this:

```
int socketTimeout = 40000; // set 40 seconds timeout value
RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,                 
                                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,     
                                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
```

Then set this setting to request queue:

```
postRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
```

I hope it is useful